# Sequelize: calculate values before creating AND updating

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

My Problem is similar to [Sequelize calculate value before saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29183093/sequelize-calculate-value-before-saving), but not quite the same.

I also have a model with one field that will be set and another one that will never be set but should be calculated before each saving operation to the database. I tried to achieve this by using the hooks.

```
var Foo = sequelize.define(
  'foo',
  {
     bar: { type: Sequelize.TEXT, allowNull: false },
     baz: { type: Sequelize.TEXT, allowNull: false }
  },
  {
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false,
    hooks: {
        // beforeCreate: setBaz
        // beforeUpdate: setBaz
        beforeValidate: setBaz
    }
  }
);

function setBaz(foo) {
  foo.baz = foo.bar + "_baz";
}
```

This works for creating but not for updating existing elements.

```
Foo.create({bar: "bar"});
```

correclty creates the following statement

```
INSERT INTO "foo" ("id","bar","baz") VALUES (DEFAULT,'bar','bar_baz') RETURNING *;
```

However,

```
Foo.findOne({where: {id: 1}})
  .then(function(foo) {
    return foo.update({bar: "foobar"});
  });
```

results in these statements

```
SELECT "id", "bar", "baz" FROM "foo" AS "foo" WHERE "foo"."id" = 1;    
UPDATE "foo" SET "bar"='foobar' WHERE "id" = 1
```

clearly only setting the new value for *bar*.

When logging the changes like this

```
function setBaz(foo) {
  console.log(foo);
  foo.baz = foo.bar + "_baz";
  console.log(foo);
}
```

I can see that the function is executed and the value is set correctly.
Before:

```
dataValues: { id: 1, bar: 'foobar', baz: 'bar_baz' },
_previousDataValues: { id: 1, bar: 'bar', baz: 'bar_baz' },
_changed: { bar: true },
```

After:

```
dataValues: { id: 1, bar: 'foobar', baz: 'foobar_baz' },
_previousDataValues: { id: 1, bar: 'bar', baz: 'bar_baz' },
_changed: { bar: true, baz: true },
```

Also the changed flags are set correctly.

I previously tried using the *beforeCreate* and *beforeUpdate* hooks instead, but this results in an error in the creation case, which seems reasonable.

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeValidationError: notNull Violation: baz cannot be null
```

Using *get/setDataValue* doesn't change a thing either

```
foo.setDataValue("baz", foo.getDataValue("bar") + "_baz");
```

The documentation on the hooks is very sparse, so any help is appreciated. How can I get sequelize to also update the calculated field?

Comment: Returning a Promise and/or calling the callback does not help either.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like *sequelize* is calculating the changed fields before calling the validate hooks. In order to overwrite this you can alter the *fields* in the passed *options*.

```
function setBaz(foo, o) {
  if(_.contains(o.fields, "bar")) { // if bar was not changed, nothing has to be done
    foo.setDataValue("baz", foo.getDataValue("bar") + "_baz");

    if(!_.contains(o.fields, "baz")) {
      o.fields.push("baz");  // Adjust the fields to be saved
      _.pull(o.skip, "baz"); // Also adjust the skipped fields, for consistency
    }
  }
  return Promise.resolve(o);
}
```